# dynamic checkboxes

Tags: c#, windows

I am new to C#.

I have about 55 checkboxes on a form to choose vaious different options, the labels and labels are dependant on 'frmSchemas.schema' from a previous form.

Is there any way I can get the values from the database to populate on the comboxes dynamically so I dont have to code to read 189 times?

I am sorry if I didnt ask the correct question.  I am using the code below but stuck after the dr.Read();  Can anyone help me...

```
string oradb = "Data Source=";
oradb = oradb + Login.db + ";";
oradb = oradb + "User Id=" + Login.user;
oradb = oradb + ";Password=" + Login.pass + ";";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();
sql = "SELECT GCOS_SCHEMA, PROGRAM_FIELD, DBFIELD,PROGRAM_LABEL FROM GENDBA.SUPTALLYACTIVITIESCONFIG where active ='Y' and GCOS_SCHEMA ='" + frmSchemas.schema + "'";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dr.Read();
```

Answer (score 2):

change dr.Read(); to

```
while(dr.Read())
{
 // loop through the table 

}
```

Comment: i thought of that but what puzzles me is how to assign them to the checkboxes?

Comment: use dr[ fieldname] to read the reader value ,and assign it to checkbox,if it isnt, explain more

Comment: which would mean that i have to do this for all checkboxes, right?

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is 55 checkboxes, thus 55 diff names to work/code with, switch to [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx) for asp.net or [CheckedListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.aspx) for winforms.